# How create custom exception (Including explicitly the control of values null) and save all exceptions in log file in Rials 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, logging, try-catch

First of all, I need to use try-catch (begin-rescue) construction for catching specific errors in controllers for each method. 
Am I right that try-catch is begin-rescue construction in rails?

What best practice is to create a custom exception, including explicitly the control of values null?

What is the approach for saving all the exceptions in a log file?

For example, I use this code to catch the standard error, when this function receives nothing as a parameter.

1. How to create a custom exception for this case? when `game_number` is `nill`
2. How to write these errors to an independent log file, using a specific library for log management (log4xxx, logging-rails, logging)?

```rb
def fizz_buzz(game_number)
    # list of the numbers, starting from @game.number
    begin
      serie_num = (game_number..Constants::LAST_NUMBER_FIZZBUZZ).to_a
    rescue StandardError => e
      print e
      # how to save this error to independent file using logging lib?
      # how using custom exception for catch errors like this - 
      # game_number = nill?
    end

    new_num = serie_num.map do |num|
      if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0
        num = 'fizzbuzz'
      elsif num % 3 == 0
        num = 'fizz'
      elsif num % 5 == 0
        num = 'buzz'
      elsif num % 3 != 0 and num % 5 != 0
        num = num
      end
    end

    return new_num.join(', ')
  end
```

Is it correct to use begin-rescue construction this way?

I use following code-statement in `config\enviroments\development.rb` for creating new logger to write to the independent file but get just an almost empty file.

```rb
config.Logger = Logger.new(ENV["PWD"] + '/fizzbuzz_log.log')
```

Got in `fizzbuzz_log.log` just this:

`# Logfile created on 2019-06-03 11:47:36 +0200 by logger.rb/56438`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class YourCustomError < StandardError
 attr_accessor :message

 def initialize(message)
    @message = message
 end

  def to_s
    "[#{message}] #{super}"
  end
end
```

That's how to create your own Error class. And then

```
 begin
   serie_num = (game_number..Constants::LAST_NUMBER_FIZZBUZZ).to_a
 rescue YourCustomError => e
  #Use logging lib to log or do custom error handling
end
```

And in your custom method whenever you regard as the error, do this.

```
raise YourCustomError.new("Error Occured. Contact the System Admin") # the message can be anything specific to your business domain's problem.
```

Comment: do you know how to log to file just all messages which have level WARN, how to log just specific messages to file?
thank you